# Classifying line layer based on number of intersection points with polygon layer

Tags: qgis, polygon, line, intersection, expression

In QGIS 3.16 in Windows 10 I have:

- a line layer `'centerline.shp'`
- a polygon layer `'o31001_AX_Gebaeude_f_12342.shp'`

I am trying to classify my line layer based on the number of intersection points with the polygon layer.

I use the Field Calculator of the line layer and wrote this:

```sql
CASE
    WHEN aggregate(layer:='o31001_AX_Gebaeude_f_12342', aggregate:='count', expression:="ID", filter:=intersects($geometry, geometry(@parent))) = 0 THEN 5
    WHEN aggregate(layer:='o31001_AX_Gebaeude_f_12342', aggregate:='count', expression:="ID", filter:=intersects($geometry, geometry(@parent))) = 1 THEN 1
    WHEN aggregate(layer:='o31001_AX_Gebaeude_f_12342', aggregate:='count', expression:="ID", filter:=intersects($geometry, geometry(@parent))) > 1 THEN 2
END
```

I can not get proper results. I think it might be a problem with the:

```
filter:=intersects($geometry, geometry(@parent))
```

How can I find if a line has an intersection with the polygon in QGIS? If yes, then how many points do they share.

Answer (score 2):

What you seem to mean is how often does each line cross the **boundary** (outline) of each polygon. When a line crosses a polygon, the number of intersection points is infinite as the intersection has the form of a line and this consists of an infinite number of points.

To count the number of crossing points with the boundary, first convert your polygons to lines using `Menu vector / Geometry tools / Polygons to lines`, than explode lines with `Menu Processing / Toolbox / Explode lines` to get a separate feature for each line segment.

Now on your `centerline` layer calculate the number of crossing points using field calculator and this expression (replace `exploded` with the name of the layer created before): `array_length (overlay_intersects( 'exploded', $geometry))`

As you already have QGIS 3.16, using [`overlay_intersects`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html?highlight=overlay_intersects#overlay-intersects) should not be a problem - this function is only [available since QGIS 3.16](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog316/index.html#port-reffunctions-to-core).

*Screenshot: the black lines are labeled with the expression from above. There are two special cases, however, where the number differs from the actual number: 1. case on the left, where the line touches exactly one point (vertex) of the polygon: as the line in fact touches two segments of the boundary (the two polygon-boundary segments starting at the vertex), it returns a value of `2`; 2. Line on the bottom: in one case (crossing points 4 and 5 from the left), the line twice crosses the same segment, thus it is counted just once - and so, the resulting value is 9 instead of 10:*
[image]